# isolate and work with certain lines in text file

Tags: python

I'm using python. I've got a text file that has the following format:

```
###########
text lines
###########
text lines
###########
text lines
###########
```

I want to run an algorithm for each segment found between two "######" lines. 
How do I reference the text lines between two "######" lines.
The number of lines between two "######" lines is not fixed.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'reference'? Simply evaluating their value while iterating through all lines in the file, ignoring the #####?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite easily with `split()`:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('###########')
    print([txt.strip() for txt in data if txt])
```

Comment: This answer looks good except for the reassignment of the context manager.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
f = open("textfile.txt")
for line in f.readlines():
   if '######' not in line:
       print(line) # evaluate and process the line here
```

Answer (score 0):

Or how about this:

```
with open("f.txt") as f:
    print(''.join(x for x in filter(lambda x: x != '###########', f.read().split("\n"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.txt`:

```
###########
line1
#
line2
######
line3
line4
line5
##########
line6
line7
```

code:

```
import re

FILE_PATH = "file.txt"

blocks = []
lines = []

with open(FILE_PATH) as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.fullmatch(r"#+(\n){0,1}", line):
            if lines:
                blocks.append(lines)
                lines = []
        else:
            lines.append(line.rstrip("\n"))  # remove rstrip if you want to keep a new line at the end of a line

# store last block (if file does not end with #+ line)
if lines:
    blocks.append(lines)

print(blocks)  # [['line1'], ['line2'], ['line3', 'line4', 'line5'], ['line6', 'line7']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering "######" doesn't contain "\n":

```
def get_chunks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().split('#'*6)[2:-1:2]
```

else:

```
import re

def get_chunks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return re.split(r'(#\n?){6}', f.read())[4:-1:4]
```